# Unable to get Google to index certain pages on website

Tags: wordpress, google-search, google-search-console, yoast

- WordPress website
- Checked and no security issues
- Checked and not black listed
- Checked correct settings in Yoast
- Checked basics in Google Search Console
- Checked asked Google to reindex pages with issues
- Pages appear in the sitemap
- 25 pages are indexed on the site so know there is no wider issue

Have a client website https://mgrplumbingandheating.co.uk/ the issue is that many of the pages are not being indexed by Google. Have taken all the above steps, and see no issue with the way pages are built.

Example page with issue indexing is https://mgrplumbingandheating.co.uk/landlords-safety-checks-berkhamsted/)

Any help would be handy, going crazy with this.

Have requested indexing of pages several times over the last 3-4 weeks.

Is there anything else I can do or try to get these pages indexed?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about SEO which is off-topic at Stack Overflow (see: [Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618)). SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

1. Once try the Rankmath SEO plugin and add the sitemap url to Google Console provided by Rankmath and check wether the pages is indexing or not.
2. Check the Yoast setting of the page which is not indexing and make sure it is set to "index"